# No stable location updates are received in CLLocationManager didUpdateLocations delegate. I don't know what is wrong

Tags: swift, core-location, cllocationmanager

I am trying to get location updates with locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]). The locations are received. But when I am debugging the app in device, I have recorded some weird events.

One was that the phone was never removed from place while debugging but it recorded different locations over a period of 15 minutes and the distance summed up to around 50meters.

Another was that when the first time the delegate was fired, it provided the correct current location, but soon it moved some 800 meters away and then restored to correct location after some time.

What I am trying to do in this app is to calculate travelled distance over time. But since I am not getting correct data, the distance I am getting is wrong.

The locationmanager has been used in this way

```
    locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation
    locationManager.distanceFilter = 1
    locationManager.activityType = .automotiveNavigation
    locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = true
```

and the lastLocation from delegate is saved and used

```
 public func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    if let bestLocation = locations.last {
        guard -(bestLocation.timestamp.timeIntervalSinceNow) < 5 || bestLocation.horizontalAccuracy > 0 else {
            return
        }
        self.lastLocation = bestLocation
    }
}
```

I am saving current location data and comparing it with the next one received every one second to calculate the distance.

So how do I fix this incorrect received location and calculate distance properly. My approach of doing this may be wrong, so please suggest me a better way of handling this.

Comment: you are testing inside? If yes, the accuracy can be that low and jumps are possible, Test outside

Comment: i will try @Volker. Thanks